# Is it ok to put html code in Django TextField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps

Is it good to put html code in a Django TextField that will be used in a blog app?

Comment: yeah its fine but watch for encoding before putting it in db

Comment: Yes. you can use HTML code in Django Textfield.

Comment: @Arpit please give tip on ways to watch for encoding.

Comment: make sure that your html has an encoding which is supported by your db

Answer (score 1):

It's all right you use any HTML in django textfield, for example, if you are using TinyMCE, this kind of list can be used very easily

Comment: How TinyMCE will help here?

Comment: If you are developing a blog app the TinyMCE provides the interface for the user manage his text, transforming simple text in HTML, this way the user can do lists, paragraphs and etc, just with the interface and you work easily with this HTML putting him in a div. If you are interested: https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce

Answer (score 1):

Use this to put html code in text field. ckeditor is great html editor with many plugin also it has django library with many customize functionality

https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor